# How to format a number up to N decimals where N is random

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatting

I want to encrypt a number up to `N` decimals. The process I use sometimes generates less decimals than `N` so I need to pad the rest with zeroes to the left. I tried this:

```
N = 5 # The number of decimals needed for encryption

encrypted = '%0Nd' % (x) # here x is a number used to encrypte the original number
```

but `N` in `encrypted` should be a number priory determined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
encrypted = '{:0{width}d}'.format(x, width=N)
```

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.6 solution with format strings:

```
encrypted = f'{d:0{N}}'
```

For example,

```
>>> d = 5
>>> N = 3
>>> f'{d:0{width}}'
005
```

Comment: both answers work perfectly, i think the method of the first line of  Jonas is much more elegant.